# Django Unit test is written but coverage report says there are missing statements

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, code-coverage

I try to get coverage reports using a simple django model.

Unit test for model was written but report says there are missing statements.

The model:

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils import FieldTracker

from generics.base_model import BaseModelMixin

class AModel(BaseModelMixin):
    record_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tracker = FieldTracker()

    class Meta(BaseModelMixin.Meta):
        db_table = 'a_model_records'

    def __str__(self):
        record _name = self. record_ name
        if record_name is None:
            record_name = "N/A"
        return record name
```

The unit test:

```
class TestAModel(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def test_amodel(self):
        record_name = "some name"
        is_active = True

        user = User.objects.first()
        record = AModel.objects.create(
            record_name=record_name,
            is_active=is_active,
            created_by_id=user.id,
        )
        self.assertEqual(str(record), record_name)
        self.assertEqual(record.name, record_name)
        self.assertEqual(record.is_active, is_active)
```

The command line code I run:

```
source activate
set -a
source local.env
set +a
coverage run --source="unit_test_app" --rcfile=.coveragerc project/manage.py test -v 2
coverage report
coverage html
```

The coverage configuration is like this:

```
[run]
omit=
    */migrations/*
    */tests/*
    */manage.py
    */apps.py
    */settings.py
    */urls.py
    */filters.py
    */serializers.py
    */generics/*

[report]
show_missing = true
```

Coverage result shows missing statements:

[image]

This is the simplest example.

There are many ignored functions by coverage which descends percentage average, but actually covered by unit tests.

Why does coverage act like this?

Comment: If you can give us a complete reproducible example, we can help debug this.

Comment: @NedBatchelder the question is already has it. Did I miss something?